# Ruby -> getting RestClient::UnprocessableEntity: 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, curl

I have something as simple as this, and I get a error 422

```
irb(main):024:0> RestClient.post 'http://dev.myServer.es/api/register', '{"first_name": "John"}', :content_type=>'application/json'

RestClient::UnprocessableEntity: 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

However, when I run the same with Curl works OK:

```
curl --location "http://dev.myServer.es/api/register" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"first_name": "John"}'


{"status": "OK"}
```

I am quite new to Ruby... but I don't know what I am missing?

Comment: why dont you check your server logs as to why it is raising a 422 error. normally thats an error encountered from a scaffold if an update or create function were to fail

Comment: it's a 3rd party server, and i don't have access to their logs

Answer (score 1):

There's an example in the docs - https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#usage-raw-url - which shows:

```
RestClient.post "http://example.com/resource", {'x' => 1}.to_json, {content_type: :json, accept: :json}
```

Try replacing:

```
:content_type=>'application/json'
```

in your call, with:

```
content_type: :json
```

Comment: Thanks for the docs -- i have tried those examples, and the change you propose, and no luck:

Comment: irb(main):021:0* RestClient.post 'http://dev.myServer.es/api/register', {"first_name" => "John"}.to_json, {content_type: :json, accept: :json}

Comment: RestClient::UnprocessableEntity: 422 Unprocessable Entity